# AngularJS service depending on resource from 2nd service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, i'm not sure, but I have 2 services, one is a user service which gets a bunch of details about the user from the server, the other being one that relies on some user details from the user service and then makes some more calls to the server to get other information.

Anyway, because of the async stuff that goes on when the 2nd service makes the calls the information required from the user server has not yet been populated.

I know Angular services can depend on one another, but not in this context it would appear?

```
factory('User', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(usersUrl, {}, {
        //The data model is loaded via a GET request to the app
        query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false},
        putupdate: {method: 'PUT', params:{}}

    });
}])
.factory('UserData', function() {
    var data = {}
    data.userinfo = {};

    if(data = {}){
    }
    return {
        updateinfo: function(newdata) {

            data.userinfo = newdata;
          //  alert(data.userinfo.user)

        },
        userinfo: data
    }
})
.factory('PlansData', ['UserData', 'User', '$rootScope', function(userData, user, $rootScope) {
    var data = {}
    data.plansinfo = {};
    //alert(userData.data.userinfo.user.email)
    if(data = {}){
    }
    return {
        updateinfo: function(newdata) {
            alert(user.query())

            data.plansinfo = newdata;
        },
        plansinfo: data
    }
}])
```

So I have a user service and a caching userdata service, but if I ever try and call anything from UserData in the PlansData service I get undefined.

How do I get plansData to wait for UserData to have some data?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: have a look at promise using $q in angular docs that may help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but this line of code:

```
if(data = {}){
}
```

In both your services is wiping out your data object. You're setting the whole data object to be {}

Comment: Hi Matthew, yeah I swiped that from another stack post, but weirdly if I remove it my models stop working, and with it, they work fine.....